# ObservedObject does not notice changes of ObservableObject Array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, mapkit

I'm having issues using ObservedObject with SwiftUI. My app has two major views:

1. The first view is called MapView and has a map with different annotations inside.
2. The second view is called MapSettingsView and has a DatePicker and a Picker for categories, in which i'm able to decide which annotations inside the MapView are visible and which are not.

Every annotation has specific properties, such as date, category and coordinates (lat, long).
Every annotations is saved inside my Firebase realtime Database, so to get them, i've build an API which calls all information i want, which works quite good.

After i've selected all properties i want inside MapSettingsView, i have a button, which calls a function (loadPublicLocations) inside my FirebaseTasks Class. This function then calls all locations, based on these properties from Firebase. This also works quite well, because i printed all wanted locations. To refresh the MapView based on the new Array of Locations, all locations inside FirebaseTasks are append to a `@Published var publicLocations = [LocationModel]()`. Inside MapView, the annotations are based on this array, which i get with the `@ObservedObject` property.

And now the Problem: Inside FirebaseTasks, all wanted locations are append to the "publicLocations" array. The MapView does not refresh, although the annotations are based on the ObservedObject `taskModel.publicLocations`.

MapView:

```
struct MapView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var taskModel = FirebaseTasks() 
    @State var showSettings = false
 
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: 25.7617,
            longitude: 80.1918
        ),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(
            latitudeDelta: 10,
            longitudeDelta: 10
        )
    )

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    showSettings.toggle()

                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3.decrease")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showSettings) {
                    MapSettings(mapViewModel: MapSettingsViewModel("all", category: "all", lat: 21, long: 21))
                                
                        }                
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.top)
            .padding(.bottom,10)
            

            Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: taskModel.publicLocations, annotationContent: { (location) -> MapMarker in    
                MapMarker(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.lat!, longitude: location.long!), tint: .red) // does not get data on refreshed MapSettings
            })
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }        
    }    
}
```

FirebaseTasks:

```
class FirebaseTasks: ObservableObject {
    
    // Model
    @Published var publicLocations = [LocationModel]() {
        didSet {
            print(publicLocations) // works
        }
    }  
    
    // Location related
    func loadPublicLocations(category: String, date: String, currentLat: Double, currentLong: Double) {
        publicLocations.removeAll()

        PublicLocationApi.system.addPublicRadiusLocationObserver(category, date: date, currentLat: currentLat, currentLong: currentLong) { (location) in
            print(location) // works
            self.publicLocations.append(location)           
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: After I simplified this code a bit so I can run it, it works perfectly find for me. The issue may lie in code you haven't shown, such as in `LocationModel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some possibilities since you didn't provide a `MapSettingsView` I cannot give a definitive reason

First, and most likely based on how you call your `.sheet` content.

You are creating separate instances of `FirebaseTasks()`, each time you call `FirebaseTasks()` it is a different instance and one does not know what the other is doing.

Second, you are creating `ObservableObject`s inside a `View` without a `@StateObject`. Both lines below are unsafe and likely result in all your Model data being lost when the `View` reloads.

```
@ObservedObject var taskModel = FirebaseTasks() 

MapSettings(mapViewModel: MapSettingsViewModel("all", category: "all", lat: 21, long: 21))
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
struct ChainedMapView: View {
    //@ObservedObject is used when the Observable Object is coming from the previous View or a class
    @StateObject var taskModel = FirebaseTasks()
    @State var showSettings = false
    
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: 25.7617,
            longitude: 80.1918
        ),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(
            latitudeDelta: 10,
            longitudeDelta: 10
        )
    )
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    showSettings.toggle()
                    
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3.decrease")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                //Creating Observable Objects in a View without StateObject is considered unsafe
                //https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app
                .sheet(isPresented: $showSettings) {
                    //Your load should be related to the region so it is visible
                    MapSettingsView(category: "all", lat: region.center.latitude, long: region.center.longitude)
                    //You have to pass the same instance of the ObservableObject
                        .environmentObject(taskModel)
                    
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.top)
            .padding(.bottom,10)
            
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: taskModel.publicLocations, annotationContent: { (location) -> MapMarker in
                MapMarker(coordinate: location.coordinates, tint: .red)
            })
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}
class FirebaseTasks: ObservableObject {
    // Model
    @Published var publicLocations = [LocationModel]() {
        didSet {
            print(publicLocations) // works
        }
    }
    // Location related
    func loadPublicLocations(category: String, date: String, currentLat: Double, currentLong: Double) {
        publicLocations.removeAll()
        
        //PublicLocationApi.system.addPublicRadiusLocationObserver(category, date: date, currentLat: currentLat, currentLong: currentLong) { (location) in
        
        //Created random objects since I dont have access to your API
        for _ in 0...10{
            let location = LocationModel(coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double.random(in: currentLat...currentLat+1), longitude: Double.random(in: currentLong...currentLong+1)), date: Date())
            print(location) // works
            self.publicLocations.append(location)
        }
    }
}

struct LocationModel: Identifiable{
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var date: Date
}
struct MapSettingsView: View{
    //If you are doing something like this you are creating a seperate instance
    //One does not know what the other is doing
    //@StateObject var taskModel = FirebaseTasks()
    
    //This is the shared Object
    @EnvironmentObject var taskModel: FirebaseTasks
    
    //You have not described how you use this
    //@StateObject var vm: MapSettingsViewModel = MapSettingsViewModel()
    let category: String
    let lat: Double
    let long: Double
    var body: some View {
        Button("load", action: {
            taskModel.loadPublicLocations(category: category, date: Date().description, currentLat: lat, currentLong: long)
        }).onAppear(perform: {
            //To put initial values into your ViewModel it is best to do it here.
            //Dont Create the ObservableObject in the body of a View
        })
        
    }
}

struct ChainedMapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ChainedMapView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly this was my fault. I didn't use the shared property `@EnvironmentObject` for the taskModel inside MapSettings and the property `@StateObject` inside MapView. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Any code which triggers a UI update in SwiftUI must run on the [main thread](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/1781006-main). If code inside an `ObservableObject` changes a `@Published` property on another thread, the change may not be reflected in the UI (even though it will correctly trigger the code inside `didSet` which is why that works).

It is common for APIs such as the `PublicLocationApi` that you are using for location services to call completion handlers on a background thread instead of the main thread. My guess is that's what is happening here. To make the UI update on the main thread, replace

```
self.publicLocations.append(location)
```

with

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.publicLocations.append(location)
}
```

The `DispatchQueue.main.async` function runs — on the main thread — the code in the closure that is passed to it, so it's useful for making UI updates.

Comment: This is a good point - but surely the warnings such as 'Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed' will pop up? The map still updates (for me, at least).